# how to read file from registry in local-entry on WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've got some js file in the registy `/_system/config/js/someJS.js` 
what path should i set in url field in local-entry?

i tried to set these paths:

```
file:config/js/someJS.js
file:/_system/config/js/someJS.js 
file:registry/resource/_system/config/js/someJS.js
```

with no luck.

i know that _system/config can be accessed through the `conf:/` but i get an error that file `conf:/js/someJS.js` referers to invalid URL.

about config: i'm running standalone configuration of esb 4.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this;

```
    // goverance/config registry
    Registry regInstance = synapseMsgContext.getConfiguration()
            .getRegistry();                        
    Object obj=regInstance.getResource(new Entry("gov:/test1.txt"),null);        
    Object obj2=regInstance.getResource(new Entry("conf:/test2.txt"),null);
```

Refer [this post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/02/accessing-registry-resources-from-class.html)